# phpMyAdmin Float Disable Round Number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have been working on a project with a lot of numbers inserted in a database table. Now that I finished the code, I was checking the values for errors and I noticed my value 3075277 would transform in 3075280 when inserted in the db and 3075255 would be 3075260.

The colummn type is Float. What should I change to disable the rounding? This one doesn't even have decimals numbers, why would it round like that? I use the default options, only changed collation to utf8_general_ci and change the type to varchar and lenght in some and float in others.

Comment: Just change the data type as BIgINT and check the result

Comment: I need to be able to store numbers with decimals too so I tough float would be the best and easier to mess with.

Comment: then you can go for Double

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna try that. But why not float if I may ask, is this a normal behavior?

Comment: The double solved it. Is it gonna make the memory bigger tough? I hope it's ok to use about 250 collumns with it.

Comment: just check the answer for the reason which you are asking in comments

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html
Floats are no exact values

Comment: If it works then please mark my answer as accepted answer there.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's not only for integer values, it's for wharever the user inputs. Also, is it weird that I keep seeing you everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you are using `FLOAT` type but getting error because you are saving big decimal number in the database. You should go for `DOUBLE`.

Although `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are similar because they store the value in approximate value, but that DOUBLE is 8-bytes, and `FLOAT` is 4-bytes.

A FLOAT is for single-precision, while a DOUBLE is for double-precision numbers.

MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

There is a big difference from floating point numbers and decimal (numeric) numbers, which you can use with the DECIMAL data type. This is used to store exact numeric data values, unlike floating point numbers, where it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

So as in your case, for larger numbers you would want `DOUBLE` instead of `FLOAT`.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with that then. I tough it was weird why it wasn't happening to all the numbers, guess it was only the big ones.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with MySQL, not Phpmyadmin.

`FLOAT` has 6-7 significant digits of precision, as you are seeing with the mangled values.  By "significant digits", I mean starting anywhere:

```
1234567xxxx.
      12345.67xxx
          1.234567xxx
          0.0000001234567xxx
```

That is the `xxx` is likely to be zeros or some kind of 'noise', not the original value you put into the column.

`DOUBLE` gives you about 16 significant digits.

`DECIMAL(9,0)` gives you 9 digits to the left of the decimal point, none afterwards.  Sort of like `INT`.

`DECIMAL(9,4)` gives you 5 (9-4) digits to the left of the point; 4 afterwards.

What kinds of numbers are you storing?  Money?  Scientific measurements?  Astronomical distances?  DT's wealth?